# POS payment from backing bean in JSF

Tags: jsf, payment-processing

I want to implement a POST call to a virtual POS for card payment proceessing. The POS is simply a server program given by the bank, and must be accesses through a form with the transaction's data. This can be done by composing a form, method post, and a set of hidden params, and then targeting the output to a new window (which is required, because from this point, the bank software takes control).
But, for security issues, I want to make the POST call from a backing bean.
Thus:

1. A button in my facelet calls a method in a RequestScoped bean. This bean has access to the transaction's data in session.
2. The bean makes some stuff.
3. **Inside** the method, I can open an URLConnection, add the params, and then call the bank's program (I assume it's a servlet).
4. Whatever the output of this servlet, it must be redirected to a new window in the client side. This new window will contain the authentication and real payment stuff, but it's the bank's software.

Which would be the correct pattern to implement that behavior by using JSF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what the goal is.  The bank web software "must take control" but you also want to control this from the server side?  When you submit the form POST to the bank server, then the payment has not been submitted?  Is there no way to pass your authentication principal and payment information in a POST?

Comment: The form POSTed to the bank's servlet simply passes amount, order id, and some optional data. The ouput of this call must be redirected to a new window. And from that window, the authentication, and card insertion take place, and also the final payment. So, my application doesn't need to store (or even read) card information.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now, you want to integrate the bank servlet functionality in your JSF application but do not want to bother with PCI compliance.

A redirect is an HTTP server response code that specifies a url to perform a GET on so you can't redirect the response of a form POST.

You also don't want to programmatically pass this POST request to the bank servlet from the server side and render the received response because you have already initiated a seperate session with bank servlet than the session exists between the user and your web application.  That is actually a serious security concern.

You can't start this Bank Servlet session through JSF unless the server is handling all HTTP communication with the bank servlet.

The way I would do this under your scenario is to use Javascript to open a new window with a regular HTML form, and set the action of the form to the bank servlet URL, and have the initial inputs of that form match the required parameter names for the HTTP post.  When this HTML form is submitted, the SSL certificate is negotiated with the users browser and the POST response will be rendered without any involvement of your web application whatsoever.  The client will maintain two seperate sessions, the session for your application as well as the session for the Bank Servlet.

This is the secure way to do this that doesn't put any PCI compliance requirements on your web application.

Comment: you are right. All is designed by the bank itself for the avoidance of having to implement PCI stuff in client applications. The way you say is the normal (and easy) way to do it. If I wanted to do it from the backing bean is because I don't want the params and bank servlet url itself be visible from page source code. The params are hidden, but anyone could view the params, including the security key generated for that transaction. Isn't that a worse security flaw?

Comment: @Carlos Possibly but then only the client computer will receive the authentication key. I can make the same argument about logging onto my bank's web app to view my checking account balance on my home computer.  The difference is that if an SSL certificate is used on the bank application then only the bank application and my browser can read that authentication key or credit card number.  If anybody is spying on my network traffic it will be encrypted to them. cont...

Comment: ... cont  I agree however that doing all communication with the bank from the server is the best approach, however **your** application will need to be PCI compliant because the credit card details will be passed to you.

Comment: ok, we agree and I will implement it with a single form, opend in a blank window. Just a point, when I say security key I am not talking abount SSL, but a key that is generated from the transaction's data: order id, amount, etc + a secret key, and then encripted through SHA. This generated key is tied to this specific transaction and it's a param in the form. Anyone could copy and resubmit this form. The bank servlet probably takes this retries into account, but I don't feel comfortable if chances are.